# Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Trying to Archive for Publishing our Xamarin.iOS app in Visual Studio on Mac but I get this error.

```
"Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
References which depend on "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Microsoft.CSharp.dll].
    /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Microsoft.CSharp.dll
      Project file item includes which caused reference "/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Microsoft.CSharp.dll".
        Microsoft.CSharp
References which depend on "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
    /Users/user193748/Documents/repos/APP/APP/APP/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/APP.dll
      Project file item includes which caused reference "/Users/user193748/Documents/repos/APP/APP/APP/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/APP.dll".
        /Users/user193748/Documents/repos/APP/APP/APP/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/APP.dll
```

This has happened since I update Xamarin.Forms from 5.0.0.2196 to 5.0.0.2244. I tried to reverting the version and deploying but the same error occurs. I also tried going from .NET Standard 2.0 to 2.1. I've had the warning before and I was still able to Archive for Publishing. The app can be deployed on Visual Studio in Windows to the Android store but for some reason the iOS side of things is preventing it.

Comment: I think you can just remove it from your dependency list, which will be added by default

Comment: It's not listed in my dependency list. I also tried adding Microsoft.Csharp 4.7.0 through Nuget and that didn't help.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen this issues floating around. I cant find a duplicate for it though, Try https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1261

Comment: Are you *sure* this is what is preventing the archive? As you mentioned, this warning has existed before, yet Archive was still possible.

Comment: Maybe there is some way to force it to use 4.0.0. I see a doc [Redirecting Assembly versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions). Try putting something in app config (not sure the exact file that would be for xamarin.ios).

Comment: Yes I am sure @ToolmakerSteve. When I try to archive, it gives me that error in the archive logs. I'm going to try the redirecting assembly versions you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to update to a new MacInCloud server which had the latest iOS version (Monterey). This solved the issue.